# Sign separating function overwrites passed in list instead of returning new one

Tags: python

I am writing a function that takes in a data set with positive and negative numbers and want to have two functions that separate the list into either positive numbers or negative numbers and replace the one you don't want with zeros. But my code is overwriting the original list it seems.

CODE:

```
##
# Data Sign Separator
##

def positive_data(data):

    #Takes in data and returns data with all negative numbers set to zero

    #holds positive data
    positive = data

    for indx, val in enumerate(positive):
        if(val<0):
            positive[indx] = 0

    return positive

def negative_data(data):

    #Takes in data and returns data with all positive numbers set to zero

    #holds positive data
    negative = data

    for indx, val in enumerate(negative):
        if(val>0):
            negative[indx] = 0

    return negative

test = [1,-1,2,-2,3,-3,4,-4,5,-5,6,-6,7,-7,8,-8]

print "original"
print test
print "positive"
print positive_data(test)
print "negative"
print negative_data(test)
```

OUTPUT:

```
original
[1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, 4, -4, 5, -5, 6, -6, 7, -7, 8, -8]
positive
[1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 6, 0, 7, 0, 8, 0]
negative
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

As you can see the positive function worked, but the negative function seems to have taken the input from the positive function....

When i run the negative function first then the positive function i get the exact opposite result:

CODE:

```
test = [1,-1,2,-2,3,-3,4,-4,5,-5,6,-6,7,-7,8,-8]

print "original"
print test
print "negative"
print negative_data(test)
print "positive"
print positive_data(test)
```

OUTPUT:

```
original
[1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, 4, -4, 5, -5, 6, -6, 7, -7, 8, -8]
negative
[0, -1, 0, -2, 0, -3, 0, -4, 0, -5, 0, -6, 0, -7, 0, -8]
positive
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code:

```
new_list = old_list
```

doesn't copy the list, it creates another name that points to the same list. So when you change one also the other is changed. To copy the list you should use:

```
new_list = old_list[:]
```

### Example

```
>>> old_list = [0, 0, 0]
>>> not_new_list = old_list     # another name for the same list
>>> not_new_list[0] = 1
>>> print old_list
[1, 0, 0]

>>> old_list = [0, 0, 0]
>>> new_list = old_list[:]      # the list is copied in new_list
>>> not_new_list[0] = 1
>>> print old_list
[0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: While `old_list[:]` is a common idiom for copying a list, a more explicit option is to use `list(old_list)`. In addition to being more clear, this will also work on any kind of iterable, not only another list. This might be handy if you wanted to apply the function to something like a tuple or a dictionary's keys (where slicing will either return an immutable type or raise an exception).

Comment: i see, i didnt realize python worked that way. I am still very new to this language. Coming from C++ it's pretty tricky to get the hang of.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to write is trivially achievable using list comprehensions:

```
>>> l = list(range(-10,10)) # python3
>>> l
[-10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> [x if x > 0 else 0 for x in l]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> [x if x < 0 else 0 for x in l]
[-10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

It produces a new list based on the existing list. What you were doing is creating a new name for the same list `positive = data`, which doesn't do a copy, so you're operating on the existing list in-place.